# UIAutomator test app meet Process crashed when using button.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

Tags: java, android, process, android-uiautomator

I'm getting the error 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.' when I use `button.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();`.

I've been tackling this issue with uiautomator for some time now and haven't been able to find solutions elsewhere.

My code:

```
package com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp;

import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.filters.SdkSuppress;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.support.test.uiautomator.UiDevice;
import android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObject;
import android.support.test.uiautomator.UiSelector;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SdkSuppress(minSdkVersion = 18)

public class MyTestClass {

    UiDevice mDevice;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        try {
            UiObject button = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Optimize"));
            button.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The log in Android studio is:

```
Testing started at 18:06 ...

01/17 18:06:41: Launching Tests in 'com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp'
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of C:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\MyUIAutomatorTestApp\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp
$ adb push C:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\MyUIAutomatorTestApp\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-androidTest.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp.test
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp.test"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp.test
Success


Running tests

$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e package com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp -e debug false com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests

Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.''. Check device logcat for details
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'
```

Note: this issue apparently relates to what UI Object it uses. If I change "Optimize" to other text in the UI, the issue may not happen. But if using "Optimize", the issue happens for sure at the point of `clickAndWaitForNewWindow`.

The phone I am using is Android 6.0.1 (API 23). Android studio version is 2.2.3.

If I change the `clickAndWaitForNewWindow` to `click`, the issue will not happen when executing click, but it will get same failure if there is another step following click, such as `mDevice.pressHome()`.

I have just extracted some Logcat when the issue happened:

```
......
01-29 08:33:26.906 21923 21936 I TestRunner: run started: 1 tests
01-29 08:33:26.906 21923 21936 I TestRunner: started: myTest(com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp.MyTestClass)
01-29 08:33:26.916 21923 21923 I MonitoringInstrumentation: Activities that are still in CREATED to STOPPED: 0
......
01-29 08:33:30.806  2286 14692 I SpeedUpDataUtils:  add pkg name is : com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp, mIsVisible is : false
......
01-29 08:33:32.356  2286  2296 I SpeedUpDataUtils: this app is needed to be killed , and is not allowed starting up background , kill this app by force !  com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp
01-29 08:33:32.366  1336  2237 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp appid\u003d10169 user\u003d0: from pid 2286
01-29 08:33:32.366  1336  2237 I ActivityManager: Killing 21923:com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp/u0a169 (adj 0): stop com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp
01-29 08:33:32.386  1336  2237 W ActivityManager: Crash of app com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp running instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}
01-29 08:33:32.386  1336  2237 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp appid\u003d10169 user\u003d0: finished inst
01-29 08:33:32.406  1336  1896 W ActivityManager: Spurious death for ProcessRecord{cd7fff5 0:com.example.taurus.myuiautomatortestapp/u0a169}, curProc for 21923: null
......
```

Comment: I've just added logcat information. I add one more information here is, it crashes after the operation of "click..." is completed.

Comment: I realized this case is testing the app that optimize phone. Seems the optimization utility "SpeedUpDataUtils" kill the test app itself. From this point, this is a correct behavior ? If so, this question should be closed ?